# Finding some rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $x$ be a rational number such that $x>1$. Prove that if $x^2<p$, then there exists a rational number $z$ such that $x<z$ and $z^2<p$.
(Please, don't say that $x<\sqrt p$ because I want to do this on rational numbers).

For the case $p=2$. I have $z=x+\frac{2-x^2}{4}$ satisfies the conditions  $x<z$ and $z^2<2$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any specific part of the problem you have issue working?

Comment: I proved for the case $p=2$. I want to prove in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

This is true
for any rational number $p$.

If rational $x$ satisfies
$x^2 < p$,
then,
since the rationals are dense,
there is a rational $q$
such that
$x < q < \sqrt{p}$,
whether or not
$p$ is a perfect squate.

Then
$x^2 < q^2 < p$.

Comment: Don't say that $\sqrt p$ because I want to do this on rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to prove there is a rational square between $x^2$ and $p$, or that the rational squares are dense.  If $x=\frac ab$ in lowest terms, consider $y_i=\frac {(ai+1)^2}{(bi)^2}=x^2+\frac{2ai+1}{(bi)^2}$.  This gets arbitrarily close to $x^2$, so just choose $i$ large enough.

Comment: I know the density property but it can not show that $z^2<p$.

Comment: it is not between $x^2$ and $p$. Find some rational number (say $z$) such that $x<z$ and $z^2<p$.

Comment: Yes it is.  All the $y_i \gt x^2$.  I claim as $i$ increases they get closer and closer to $x^2$.  At some point they are close enough to be less than $p$  With a little analysis you can find the exact $i$ where this happens, but the point is the $i^2$ in the denominator dominates the $i$ in the numerator.